# List command separating multiplicative terms

Tags: functions

I am trying to separate and store additive terms via the List command. For instance I want "AB+CD+XY" to be stored as {AB, CD, XY}

This has worked well, but when there is only one term (only multiplication), the List command separates that multiplicative term. This is undesired for me.

For instance, how can I make "AB" simply be stored as {AB} and not {A,B}. I am using a for loop and need this to be automated.

Comment: `List @@ (a b + c d + x y)` or  `(a b + c d + x y) /. Plus -> List`.

Comment: Thank you, but the code above I believe separates "ab+cd+xy" into {ab,cd,xy}  I have accomplished this but when the code is searching through equations and finds only "ab" i need the code to store it as one term {ab} not as two {a,b}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In Wolfram Language there is a VERY big difference between `ab` and `a b`.  The first is the symbol `ab` the second is really `a*b`.  When talking about your problem, it would help a great deal to be clear EXACTLY what inputs and outputs you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I am performing the List function on A*B. The outcome it yields is {A,B}. My desired outcome is {A*B}.                                                            Again, I am trying to create a for loop that will separate A*B+C*D into {A*B, C*D}, but when this for loop encounters A*B, I also need it to output {A*B} and not {A,B}

Comment: @ChrisMason I'm afraid that your last comment confused me more than it helped. Please take a look at [How to format posts using Markdown](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), then edit your question ("edit" link under the question) with that information. A few more things: 1) show us the code you tried already that does *not* work for you; 2) do not use uppercase variable names, especially for one-letter variables: they may conflict with built-ins.

Comment: Thank you I will look into your recommendations. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can use replacement rules. For instance,

```
a b + c d + e f /. {a__Plus :> List @@ a, x_ z_ :> {x z}}
(*{a b, c d, e f}*)
a b /. {a__Plus :> List @@ a, x_ z_ :> {x z}}
(*{a b}*)
```

This takes advantage of how `ReplaceAll` works in terms of the order of the list of replacement rules. It applies the first, and then applies the second to expressions not yet replaced. Naively, if we were to try

```
a b + c d + e f /. a__Plus :> List @@ a /. x_ z_ :> {x z}
```

this would yield

```
(*{{a b}, {c d}, {e f}}*)
```

Caveat: this isn't tested on nested expressions, so use with caution.